# Python psycopg2 check row exists

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

In Python psycopg2 how can I check if a row exists?

```
def track_exists(self, track_id):
    cur = self.conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT fma_track_id FROM tracks WHERE fma_track_id = %s", (track_id,))
    if cur.fetchall() > 0:
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

Currently I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "mumu.py", line 38, in track_exists
if cur.fetchall() > 0:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Don't use `fetchall()` (which returns a list, which is never 'larger than 0'), use `fetchone()`:

```
def track_exists(self, track_id):
    cur = self.conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT fma_track_id FROM tracks WHERE fma_track_id = %s", (track_id,))
    return cur.fetchone() is not None
```

`fetchone()` returns `None` if there is nothing to fetch, and testing against `is not None` gives you a handy boolean value to return directly.

Comment: with fetchone() I am still getting `return cur.fetchone() is not None
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Then post the *full* traceback in your question, that error makes no sense, and doesn't sound like it is thrown here. None of this code uses item access.

Comment: I was reloading with `from myModule import Database` and it was not reloading properly. Works now :)

Comment: Good. Note that my comment on `fetchall()` still stands.

Comment: Should you also quote the %s here? I read that Postgres automatically converts all unquoted usernames to lower case

Comment: @committedandroider: no, `%s` is a sql parameter. The database driver or database fills in the value of the `track_id` parameter there, after handling escaping, and modern databases can re-use the query plan for statements with parameters for future queries.

Answer (score 20):

Using [`exists`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) will allow Postgresql to stop searching at the first occurrence in instead of searching until exhausted:

```
exists_query = '''
    select exists (
        select 1
        from tracks
        where fma_track_id = %s
    )'''
cursor.execute (exists_query, (track_id,))
return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Another advantage is that it will always return a single row containing a boolean value which can be used directly without further interpretation.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily handled it by using [`rowcount`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount). This is what [psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/index.html) documentation mention about [`rowcount`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount),

> This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that the last execute*() produced (for DQL statements like SELECT) or affected (for DML statements like UPDATE or INSERT).
>
> The attribute is -1 in case no [execute*()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#execute) has been performed on the cursor or the row count of the last operation if it can’t be determined by the interface.

So below examples will give you better understand about how to use [`rowcount`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount).

---

**example - 1**

```py
>> # if your SELECT query doesn't have any values you'll get 0 as the output
>>> query_1 = 'SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 0;'
>>> cursor.execute(query)
>>> cursor.rowcount
0
```

---

**example - 2**

```py
>>> query_2 = 'SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 1;'
>>> cursor.execute(query)
>>> cursor.rowcount
1
```

---

**example - 3**

```py
>>> # no LIMIT in the query, so you'll get the whole row count
>>> query_3 = 'SELECT * FROM some_table;'
>>> cursor.execute(query)
>>> cursor.rowcount
14000
```

---

**example - 4**

```py
>>> # this query won't return anything, so you'll get -1 as the rowcount
>>> query_4 = 'CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table;'
>>> cursor.execute(query)
>>> cursor.rowcount
-1
```

---

So you can modify your function like below,

```py
def track_exists(self, track_id):
    cur = self.conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT fma_track_id FROM tracks WHERE fma_track_id = %s", (track_id,))

    # if cur.rowcount > 0:
    #     return True
    # else:
    #     return False

    return cur.rowcount > 0  # more Pythonic way
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** If you execute `UPDATE` query, you'll get updated row count for [`rowcount`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount). So basically [`rowcount`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount) will display how many rows affected by your query. `CREATE` query won't affect to any of the rows, so that's why you get `-1` for [`rowcount`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount).

Answer (score -1):

```
def track_exists(self, track_id):
    cur = self.conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT fma_track_id FROM tracks WHERE fma_track_id = %s", (track_id,))
    if len(cur.fetchall()) > 0:
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

Comment: While you did fix the OP's code, the 3.5 year old other answer is *much* more efficient. As such, this isn't likely to help future readers very much.