# psycopg2 how to check if a record with same attribute values exists

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Is there an easy way to check given a table and a record, if another record already exists in the table that happens to have the same attribute values as the given record? I need to be able to check this for a number of different tables and records. So a general query would be perfect.

for example: say we have a table with attributes gender and age. We're also given a record Male, 32

I need a way to check whether the table already has a record Male, 32. (but then generally, for any table)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with psycopg2, but are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449048/python-psycopg2-check-row-exists)?

`select count(1) from users where gender = 'Male' and age = 32;` would be one way to do it, then you can just check that the result > 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module from psycopg. So something like:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql  
con = psycopg2.connect(dsn)
tbl_name = "some_name"
qry = sql.SQL("select count(*) from {table_name} where gender = %(gd)s and age = %(age)s").format(table_name=sql.Identifier(tbl_name))
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(qry, {"gd": "Male", "age": 32 })
ct = cur.fetchone()[0]
```